# What causes mercury to expand equaly unregarded what the temperature increase is?

Tags: physical-chemistry, temperature, density

Mercury seemed to be a good liquid to use in thermometers. But why are most liquids expanding non-linearly with increase of temperature compared to other liquids?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15944/why-is-mercury-used-in-thermometers http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13584/what-is-the-reason-for-anomalous-expansion-of-water/13588?s=5|0.0617#13588

Comment: Note that the thermal expansion of mercury is _not_ purely linear, but is linear enough for an OK thermometer from 0 to 100C. NIST points to 'A Critical Evaluation of the Thermophysical Properties of Mercury, G.J.F. Holman and C.A. ten Seldam, in J. Phys. Chem. Ref. Data. 23(5) 807-827 (1994) for their preferred values.

Comment: The small but not zero thermal expansion is due to its mass and the fact that its liquid range is almost 400° C. Few other room temperature liquids have such large ranges.